# Web application that creates SPARQL query from user input (predetermined keywords) and gives result back to user

Tags: user-interface, sparql, rdf

I want to create a web application that has a front end. The user will search with some keywords and it will trigger a SPARQL query that will run on knowledge graph or ontology. Then the results of the query will be shown back to the user on the UI.

I have a simple ontology of machine learning models built with Protégé. It has a property of "accuracy of model". The user wants to search a model with 90% accuracy and this web application should search and show the models name and details to the user on the UI. There should be a dropdown which has different accuracy values on the page and the user will select any one of them. Then he will search for the model.

I tried using NLP techniques but it was too difficult for me, as I don't have much knowledge about those techniques.

I know about OWL, RDF, SPARQL, Apache jena.
Can anyone help me with the strategy or the tools that I should use for this application.

Any help is appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: it doesn't matter what you use, it's a web application. there are plenty of programming languages and frameworks to create a web app. And for SPARQL querying, either you load the ontology into a local triple store which makes it possible to query it via HTTP or you use a SPARQL API in the progamming language of your choice. Like for Python and Javascript there are well known libs. Nevertheless, you question is way to broad for StackOverflow and asking for tools is also not the thing SO is made for. But yeah, Javascript or Python and their RDF lib will work for you

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will definitely look for the libraries as you mentioned.